# Azure Webjobs on .net core

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

Is Azure Webjobs SDK on net core still in preview state or it is released? When I am trying to create Azure Webjobs project in Visual Studio Professional 2017 (version 15.9.4), I don't see an option to create webjobs project from .net core though it shows to create a webjobs project in .net framework.

Comment: Have a look at [WebJobs in Azure with .NET Core 2.1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredev/2018/08/22/webjobs-in-azure-with-net-core-2-1/)

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest Visual Studio and Azure Functions SDK and when you create a new functions project you'll have the option to select .NET Core.